# Convert object input parameters to give them types so that TypeScript doesn't complain

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript React app. I wanted to find and use a Hook to process keystrokes. I found the following JS component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useKeyPress = (targetKey) => {
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);

  const downHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) setKeyPressed(true);
  };

  const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) setKeyPressed(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return keyPressed;
};
export default useKeyPress;
```

To get TypeScript to stop harassing me about missing types, I started notating them. The first was easy: I changed `const useKeyPress = (targetKey) => {` to `const useKeyPress = (targetKey:string) => {` and that worked fine.

But next, I wanted to annotate `const downHandler = ({ key }) => {`. When I tried to say   `const downHandler = ({ key:string }) => {`, TypeScript refused to compile because I'm assuming key:string looks like an object key-value pair. The specific error message was:

> 'string' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
>
> Binding element 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

So now I'm stumped. How do I annotate the TypeScript so it compiles?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second problem is related to what you are telling TypeScript/JavaScript to do. In this case `const downHandler = ({ key:string }) => {` is telling TypeScript to destructure an object which has a property named `key` and you want to store the value of property `key` into the parameter `key`, but when you specify '{ key:string }' you are indicating that you are receiving (destructuring) a key/value pair, but with the wrong syntax.

The actual syntax to achieve what you want is specifying an interface, which could be:

1. Inline interface. In this sample, we are sending an object with multiple properties, one of them `key` which is of type string.

```
const downHandler = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) setKeyPressed(true);
};
```

2. ...or...with an explicit interface.

```
interface IMyType {
  key: string
}

const downHandler = ({ key }: IMyType) => {
    if (key === targetKey) setKeyPressed(true);
};
```

You can find a good explanation, and samples, about destructuring in this post: https://medium.com/@rileyhilliard/es6-destructuring-in-typescript-4c048a8e9e15